# Set xTime on Condition Inside KeyEvent

Tags: c#, winforms

is there a way i can set a condition that after pressing key and if 5seconds already passed then a certain method will be executed .

e.g i have keyup event in gridview:

```
private void Grid_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
    }
    else 
    {
        if (atimehasalreadypassed == 5seconds)
        {
           //execute
        }
    } 
}
```

problem with this was count might start after passing keyDown so it would be only 1sec.
so i need some count outside U.I thread / within background thread ...

Note: i dont need delay, i just need to know if 5seconds already passed after keyEvent ...

Comment: You mean you want to know if the user has held the key down for more than 5 seconds?

Comment: if 5seconds already passed after keyUp @dbc

Comment: A little bit of clarification would certainly help. Do you want to find out if 5 seconds passed between two subsequent presses of "key"?

And if so, do you want to react to let´s say a press of "A" and then "B" or do you only want to react to "A" and then "A" again?
Should it keep a timing for every key? Only the last one?

Your question is not very clear.

Comment: @Nicolas, if i press "A" then "B" in lessthan 5seconds then timer shouldnt not run ... but if i press "A" then 5seconds has passed then it should go to method ...

Comment: What timer?

I am still not 100% sure I understand what you are aiming for. If you want your program to register a keyPress, and then after 5 seconds do something the following might work:

`using System.Timers;`

`private Timer _timeoutTimer = new Timer(5000);
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _timeoutTimer.Elapsed += TimeoutTimerOnElapsed;
        }

        private void TimeoutTimerOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs)
        {
            _timeoutTimer.Stop();
            // do stuff
        }

`

Comment: `private void Grid_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
            }
            else 
            {
                _timeoutTimer.Stop();
                _timeoutTimer.Start();
            } 
        }`

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you need:

```
    private void Grid_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
        }
        else 
        {
            if (SecondsPassed(5))
            {
               //execute
            }
        } 
    }

    private DateTime _lastCallTime = new DateTime();
    private bool SecondsPassed(double seconds)
    {
        // calculate time difference
        var timeSpan = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks - _lastCallTime.Ticks);
        // reset timing
        _lastCallTime = DateTime.Now;

        if (timeSpan.TotalSeconds > seconds)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Note that you might want to initialize "_lastCallTime" manually, depending on your usage.

Comment: is TotalSeconds = milliseconds? i found it a bit fast compare to ordinary

Comment: No, TotalSeconds is total Seconds and fractions of seconds. For example: 1 Minute 2 Seconds and 600 Milliseconds would return "62.6".

Comment: everytime i press key it always returns true reason in less than 5seconds totalSeconds gives higher than 5 ...

Comment: Then you didn´t use the code I provided. If you look into my "SecondsPassed" Function you will see that there is a line which resets the time measurement. I tested it before posting and again right now, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: It should be simple by just assigning `Interval` property to `5000` and call a method in `timer_tick` event and you can reset `Timer.Enabled` property in `KeyDown` event. It just a waste of time.

Comment: @Shell which is what I suggested as an alternative in the comments to the original question. That however will result in the program doing something 5 seconds after the event (effectively a delay) which Elegiac suggested he does not want. Plus: By using Timer_tick you are suggesting the Forms.Timer class which runs on the UI Thread, which is another thing Elegiac did not want.

Comment: Then OP can simply create a thread and place `Thead.Sleep(5000)` at the first line of the method. I really cant understand what OP wants.

Comment: @Shell That would freeze the UI completely for 5 Seconds, which is definitely not what is wanted.

Comment: @Nicolas I am talking about `thread` which will run separately.  `Thread.Start()` and we can reset that thread on `KeyDown` event.